# Which is the right html tag in this situation

Tags: html, css

I'm planing to add an image into the input field so if you click on that image the text in the input field will be clear.

I'm planing to use absolute positioning. 
My question is which html tag is the best candidate for this situation?

Here is the code that I use.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #search_form {
                width: 380px;
                height: 110px;
                position: relative;
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#43689a), to(#6399e7));

            }

            #search_form input {
                width: 300px;
                height: 30px;
                border-radius: 18px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                margin-left: 70px;
                margin-top: 40px;
                padding-left: 36px;
            }

            #search_form input:focus {
                outline: none;
            }
            #search_form button {
                position: absolute;
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
                background: url(f.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
                border: 0;
                top: 47px;
                left: 85px;
                cursor: hand;
                text-indent: -9999px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="search_form">
            <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search....">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best candidate for adding an image?  `img`?

Comment: Are you sure you need a reset button? I have *never* clicked on a reset button *on purpose* in my whole life.

Comment: I'm just trying different techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `<img>`

Usually you will want to use an `<img>` tag for most image work.

```
<img src="blah.png" />
```

#### CSS `background-image`

You can also use a plain `<div>` and set its `background-image` rule in CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="handsome-bg"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.handsome-bg {
    background-image:url(blah.png);
}
```

#### Which one?

Both have up sides and down sides but in general stick to `<img>`. Something that `<img>` has more trouble doing for example is selecting a different image depending on screen size or density (I want to use high-res images on a retina display).

Answer (score 0):

Outside of using an `<img>` tag you could place an image in the background of the input field.

```
 #search_form input { background:url(../imagepath/image.jpg); }
```

Comment: This would not be clickable.